# Text not updating as expected using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if anyone could explain to me what is going on here?

```js
var testNo = $("#test").text()

$("ul li a").click(function() {
  $("#test").text($(this).text());
  console.log(testNo)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="test">1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" >1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" >3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

It is strange to me why this wouldn't update the list item as you click using this method. However, if you change the javascript to;

```
$("ul li a").click(function() {
  var testNo = $("#test").text()

  $("#test").text($(this).text());
  console.log(testNo)
})
```

It shows the value as one behind, but set the following as;

```
$("ul li a").click(function() {

  $("#test").text($(this).text());
  var testNo = $("#test").text()

  console.log(testNo)
})
```

and it has the desired behaviour.

Is there a way to achieve what this last code snippet gives me, but by using the first code format?

Let me know something doesn't make sense,

thanks

Comment: It *does* update the list item. Are you confused by the logging output in the demo?

Comment: because `var testNo = $("#test").text()` does not update everytime the text is changed.... It reads the value at that time and stores it, it is not a reference that updates. The code works perfectly fine. If you want the latest, you need to read it after you update it.

Comment: `epascarello` is bang-on correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the testNo variable text, then only it will show the latest text. Try:

```js
var testNo = $("#test").text()

$("ul li a").click(function() {
  testNo = $(this).text();
  $("#test").text($(this).text());
  console.log(testNo)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="test">1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" >1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" >3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first code testNo is set globally and take the value at page load in the second and 3th it is set locally so the value changes at each click event ,

In the second the value is incremented before the text is change so it captures the previous altered value, the 3th the value is saved after the text is saved so testNo is display the updated value

Answer (score 1):

It's all about when you get the value of the `$('#test').text()` -- because you then go on to change the source value.

Your code does two things: (1) It reads #test and stores its value as testNo, and (2) it gets the text from the clicked anchor tag and puts that value into #test. So two things change: the var testNo and #test.

If you save the value of #test as var testNo, then change the value of #test before displaying testNo, they will have different values.

I think what you want to do is this:

```js
$("ul li a").click(function() {
   var testNo = $(this).text()
   $("#test").text(testNo);
  console.log(testNo)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="test">1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" >1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" >3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```